Bleaching yellow bone saddle?
Can the inner part of cattle bone that's yellowish be bleached white?
I bought an oversized bone guitar saddle blank, which was completely white on the outside. After I cut it to shape, I noticed parts of the now exposed interior are a dull yellow color.
I'm trying to bleach it using a 10% hydrogen peroxide solution, but it's not having much of an effect.

Usually you’d bleach bone in hydrogen peroxide, maybe you piece is just discolored quite heavily? Saddle blanks are not expensive, so maybe try a different one.

Not an answer per se, but compensated saddles are readily available at little cost, and would only need their height changing, thus retaining the colour.

Hydrogen Peroxide is a common way of bleaching natural bone fittings. 10% solution should do it, but expect to have the bone soak for 24 hours or more.
You can also use hair bleach which can be available up to 12%, sometimes called 40-strength or 40-volume.
Anything over 12% can be dangerous to work with. There are some pool shock products (used to clear water in swimming pools) that can have peroxide level up to 50%
A Luthier I know uses a hair bleaching paste and places the bone parts in a box with the UV light that he uses for setting UV reactive resin. I don't know if it actually speeds up the process or not.

From what I recall, "sun bleaching" for paper conservation, they filter UV because it can break down the paper, but I think for bone, UVA and UVB from the sun is more effective (and possibly faster) than a light source with no (or little) UV component. I do wonder if the bleaching paste acts a masking compound (i.e. opaque) though.
